# fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression

Tags: visual-c++, msdn

I have got a statement in my code:

```
#if DEBUG==0
```

this works fine in gnu g++ but it fails in VC++.
Can anyone explain what is wrong with this.

I have already read msdn help on this topic.
so, if debug is defined as 1 then this is false i.e.0, so it should work and similarly if debug=0

Can anyone suggest how to correct this.
My code has to be compiled both in linux and win.

Thanks

Comment: Works for me Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, whether DEBUG is undefined, 0 and 1. I only get that error if it's defined but not set to something i.e. `#define DEBUG` or `-DDEBUG` but no value.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It was defined but not set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it like:

```
#if DEBUG
```

Though I should add that typically one checks if DEBUG is defined, not if it is 1.  To declare you simply say:

```
#define DEBUG
```

Check if it is not defined with:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
```

Comment: I know, but this is not my code. I am just including someone's header file in my code which has got this statement and I can't just change it.

Comment: Just do an #ifdef DEBUG followed immediately by #if DEBUG and in the else do #undef DEBUG so that ultimately DEBUG remains consistenly defined if debug is in effect and undefiend otherwise as it would be normally.  +1 to Rup for the idea.  :)